# java physical font fallback

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, itext, fallback

I got the following problem:

In general, I have an application where people can type and paste any type stuff, and later they can export it to PDF. 
You can enter any type of unicode, so I need to support many characters. 
My current solution is to use a composite font, with which everything works fine. But with the PDF-output I'm getting into hassle. 
The PDF-library doesn't handle the composite font well. I have already tried several ways to make it work (and already asked a question about that in stackoverflow), but I got no solution. 
The library (iText) uses a font mapper to match fonts.

The composite font i am talking about is initialized this way:

```
    private static final Font WIDGET_FONT = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getFont("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE);
```

So my next hope is to get rid of the composite font via using a pure "physical font + fallbacks" - solution. I already now use one fallback font for the special emoji's my users can embed, and it works fine. Also the PDF-library handles it well, since it just inserts the glyphs as little images. Not selectable or anything, but that's fine for me. 
This solution would look like this:

```
    // Font creation  
    private static final Font WIDGET_FONT = new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE);
 // Fallbacks are in the /lib/fonts/fallback - folder in java
```

The terms "physical" and "logical" fonts, as well as the whole composite-font-solution, I got from this source: 
http://elliotth.blogspot.de/2007/04/far-east-asian-fonts-with-java-7-on.html

But when I use just a physical font + fallbacks, many uncommon unicode-chars don't get rendered. Somehow the fallback mechanism doesn't work on those, even though everything is configured well. I have already tried several things with the java font configuration file and the fallback-folder, but nothing worked.

Can anybody help?

Greetings,

Andy

Comment: Can you be more specific about what “use a composite font” means, and what “physical font + fallbacks” means?  Does the former mean creating a custom TrueType file?  Does the latter mean adding fonts to a JRE's `lib/fonts/fallback` directory?  How are you making use of these fonts when you create your PDF?  Code would be easier to understand than an elaborate description, even if it's example code.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I just updated my post with your tips

Comment: if your fallback  is a font, but they become "pictures" in the PDF, then that does not "work fine", because it means that what is a font on the java side, is not a font on the pdf side. That solution is going  to going to generate "not text" once you use additional fallbacks for text not supported by your primary font. Looking at http://itextpdf.com/support, they want you to post here on stackoverflow with the `itext` tag, which you forgot to do. I've edited your tags to include it.